# Moving Fortran listings from an online book or paper to FORTRAN-compatible formats

Tags: text-editor

Consider an online book or paper with some whiz-bang FORTRAN code listings you want to copy over as input to a FORTRAN compiler. In MS/WINDOWS I can use ctrl-a to put that text in a buffer. Now I want to save that text in a form that is compatible with FORTRAN formats. If I just blithely paste it in an MS Word file, or a .txt file, I am concerned that the formats will get all screwed up (e.g., hidden formatting characters might be inserted) and not be compatible with what a FORTRAN compiler likes to see. What is the safest way to download the text from the buffer to ensure compatibility later on? I seem to remember that the old DOS O/S provided a way to do this.

Comment: This is only tangentially about programming and more about generic computer software. Also not in any way specifically about Fortran. Just use any text editor. That means not a word processor, simple text editor. There are many, Notepad is the most simple one in MS Windows.

Comment: However, welcome and I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. Your questiin might become closed. Do not take that too harsh.

Comment: In a .txt file there should not be any bad formatting present. In a normal text editor you can indeed just paste and save. There is nothing more to this. Just don't save it as .doc or .rtf or .odf or anything similar. There are dedicated programming text editor, I suggest to try one. They make the life much easier in comparison to the simple Notepad.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your patience and for your helpful comments !